# JavaScript regular expression precedence rules

Tags: javascript, regex

How does this work?

#### The code:

```
a = {
    replacers: {
        YYYY: function () {
            return this.getFullYear();
        },
        dd: function () {
            var me = this,
                day = me.getDate();

            return (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
        },
        d: function () {
            var me = this;

            return me.getDate();
        }
    },
    format: function (date, format) {
        var replacers = a.replacers;

        // I just added a plus to get multiple digits and it works...
        return format.replace(/\{([Yd]+)\}/g, function (str, p1) {
            var formatter = replacers[p1];
            if (formatter)
                return formatter.call(date);
        });
    }
};

document.write(a.format(new Date(), '{dd} {d} {YYYY} {d} {dd}'));
```

**The result:**

```
05 5 2013 5 05
```

Am I correct in using the `+` to identify one or more charater?

Are there any pitfalls here when I expand the replace functions? I'm mostly worried that there will be a match on `{xx}` before `{xxx}`.

Comment: Not sure what you understood there, but `+` is a greedy quantifier while `+?` is lazy. And `(x+)?` is something else entirely.

Comment: not being so super on regex i'm just worried that the match will go wrong. i just want to make sure that {xxx} is always handled before {xx} is always handled before {x}. if the current code does that... i'm good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`([d]+)`, or just `(d+)`, will greedily match and capture one or more `"d"`.

`([d]+)?`, or just `(d*)`, will greedily match and capture zero or more `"d"`.

For *lazy* matching the `?` needs to be added immediately after the quantifier, i.e. `d+?`, but there is no need for it here as `d+\}` and `d+?\}` will always make exactly the same match, as for the `}` to be matched all the `d`s before it need to be matched.

Laziness is only relevant when there are options about which particular characters can be matched. For example, when matching the string `"ddde"`, then `d+.` would match the whole string and `d+?.` would match just `dd` because the `.` can match the second `d`.

You say you want to "make sure that `{xxx}` is always handled before `{xx}` is always handled before `{x}`", but the one that is earlier in the string is the one that will be matched first regardless of whether the match is lazy or not. I don't see how it would matter here anyway - perhaps you could explain further why that would be a problem.

It is not clear from your code why you are using a `replaces` object when it seems simpler just to include its functionality within the callback to `replace`. And your choice of identifiers, `replace` and `replaces` involving the `replace` method call, and `format` as a function and one of its parameters, makes the code difficult to read.

Comment: it can't be (d+). there will be more coming like ([YMdhms]+). it must only be the same char repeating. i'll see if i can update the example with some more code when i've renamed some stuff and cleaned it up some.

Comment: just got it. "earlier in the string is the one". I was thinking all wrong.